# Do I really have to do a fresh install every 6/9 months? Updating causes problems

Tags: installation, upgrade, 10.04

Perhaps the only thing that still tethers me to Mac OSX and Windows 7, aside from specific program suites, is the fact that I am not required to upgrade every few months.

Windows and OSX silently (if you choose) roll out security updates to your system to give you the latest features to extend the longevity of your install.

I don't feel that I get this with Ubuntu.  I'm forced to choose whether I want the latest release or LTS.

Is there no "best of both worlds" option?  Is there an easier method of upgrading that I'm missing?  I've just had so many problems with botched configs that it seems easier to just be easier to wipe the drive, rather than upgrade.

I know it's lack of foresight on my part, but I forgot to back up my samba configs on the last go.  Even now do I still find myself crawling back into my configuration to change something.

Comment: You Have Upgrading Problems Using Software Updater And Terminal?

Comment: I tried to update using the software updater, which completely wrecked my 8.04 install when trying to upgrade to 10.04.  Now I'm looking to upgrade again, and frankly, I'm afraid to given my past experience.

Comment: Frankly you can just make a /home partition or make backups.

Comment: Why exactly are you *required* to upgrade? Install a LTS version and stick to it. If you want newer software, add a PPA with a newer version. This is the "best of both worlds".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only use LTS releases you rarely ever have to upgrade.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Comment: What if you want the improvements provided by Unity 7, though?  From what I can tell, this upgrade is impossible on LTS.

Comment: If you want the newest features over stability then just upgrade everyime a new version comes out, Or if you are really into bleeding edge take a look at Manjaro or Arch.

Answer (score 0):

I Recommend you take a look at this: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html

Comment: I looked at this, but it seems like there is too much "magic" happening under the hood.  Do I simply backup my existing system, update, and then give it a shot?

I don't see how this is going to prevent the configuration issues I encountered previously.